# Django Form Init Key Error With Kwargs

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to override the **init** method on this form I have. It looks like so:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    fr = None
    if kwargs.get('friend', False):
        fr = Friend.objects.get(pk=kwargs.get('friend'))
    super(CreateFriendForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.fields["{}_house".format(fr.name)] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Houses.objects.all(), required=False)
```

So, I want to grab the friend kwargs and use it as you see above. Depending on what friend is passed, I'll add a field. In my tests, I pass the following data:

```
    data = {
        "user": self.user.pk,
        "friend": self.friend.pk,
        "language": 'en'
    }
    friend = self.form(data)
    # Validity
    self.assertTrue(friend.is_valid())
    friend.save()
```

However, I get an error saying that there is a key error at:

```
if kwargs.get('friend', False):
```

I'm passing the necessary data (friend, user, etc), but it doesn't seem to be in the kwargs. What's the issue here? Thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between `fr` and `friend`? You use `friend.name` but set `fr` to a friend object.

Comment: @ozgur There's none. Was a typo on my part, my bad.

Comment: what's the exact error you are getting?

Comment: You are passing the dictionary as a normal parameter. You are not unpacking the values `friend = self.form(**data)`.

Comment: You are not using the `language` value anywhere, which will give an error when you call super, as the Form doesn't accept a language param.

Comment: @BogdanIulianBursuc Your first comment was the issue. If you pose it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was that I was passing the data into the form as an arg instead of as a kwarg. Changing:

```
friend = self.form(data)
```

to:

```
friend = self.form(data=data)
```

Fixed the main problem that I was having.